# IFrame In AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to bind iframe in a div that is returning by my database,

```
<iframe width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;315&quot; src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/zvo9m_e8ekA&; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allow=&quot;autoplay; encrypted-media&quot; allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Is this possible to bind in following div

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">
```

Comment: are you returning it as string? You might need `ng-bind-html`

Comment: Yes, I'm returning it as string. I've already tried ng-bind-html but it's not working

Comment: you need to explain why it's not working. Did you inject the `ngSanitize` module? Have you escaped quotes in your string? Do you have any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [`$sce` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce) in conjunction with ng-bind-html in order to parse the string as safe HTML.

If your string is:
`"<iframe width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;315&quot; src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/zvo9m_e8ekA&; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allow=&quot;autoplay; encrypted-media&quot; allowfullscreen></iframe>"`

Then you need to replace the `&quot;` with apostrophes and then parse it as safe HTML, as such:

```
dummy.unsafeIframeCode = "<iframe width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;315&quot; src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/zvo9m_e8ekA&; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allow=&quot;autoplay; encrypted-media&quot; allowfullscreen></iframe>";

dummy.unsafeParsedIframeCode = dummy.unsafeIframeCode.replace(/\&quot\;/gi, "'");

dummy.safeIframeCode = $sce.trustAsHtml(dummy.unsafeParsedIframeCode);
```

And simply bind it in HTML as such:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy" ng-bind-html="dummy.safeIframeCode">
```

[Full working JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Protozoid/5s9reuLq/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Protozoid

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bind-html` willn't work for binding your *iFrame*, because the sanitizer is protecting your app from potential **XSS** attacks.

If you trust/control the data source completely, you can look into using `trustAsHtml` 
e.g. `scope.trustedData = $sce.trustAsHtml(content);` in your directive controller(where content is your iFrame "`<iframe.../>`"), and `<div ng-bind-html="trustedData"></div>` in the DOM. It'll do the task for you.